# Is it a known example of adic transformation ? (1)

Tags: ergodic-theory, ds.dynamical-systems

Here is a Bratelli-Vershik graph: [alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/64jrg.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/64jrg.jpg)

This graph should (I do not master this topic) define a Vershik adic transformation $T$ on its  path space.

- What are the invariant measure(s) on the path space for which $T$ is ergodic ?
- Is $T$ (isomorphic to) a known example of transformation in ergodic theory ?

**EDIT 26/08/2012:** I finally don't understand why $T$ is isomorphic to the dyadic odometer, as claimed in RW's answer below. Below are some observations about this graph.

- To be sure of the definition of the graph, using Vershik terminology it is given by the Markov compactum $(M_n)$ where $M_n$ is the $n\times (n+1)$-matrix obtained by concatenating the $n \times n$-identity matrix with a column of ones:
  $$M_n=\begin{array}{cccccc} 1 & 0 & \cdots &\cdots & 0 & 1 \\\
  0 & \ddots & \ddots & & \vdots  & \vdots \\\
  \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & & \vdots & \vdots \\\  
  \vdots & & & & 0 & \vdots \\\
    0 & \cdots & & 0 & 1 & 1
  \end{array}$$
- In figure below this is an example of the action of $T$, the blue path becomes the red path:

[image]

- According to the link between adic and cut-and-stack the transformation $T$ should correspond to a cutting and stacking construction looking like:

[image]

Is there something wrong in my understanding ? Could you elaborate a little the isomorphism between $T$ and the dyadic odometer ? Perhaps I could convince myself that the cutting and stacking construction asymptotically coincides with the odometer, but I don't see the isomorphism between the paths space of this adic graph and the paths space of the usual adic graph of the odometer.

**EDIT (later):** I have checked that the cut-and-stack procedure is indeed an approximation of the dyadic odometer. Hence RW is right but still I don't see the isomorphism between the paths space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two edges going out of every vertex of this graph; label the vertical one with 0, and the other one with 1. Thus, paths in your graph can be parametrized by the space of 0,1 sequences. If one removes the vertical path corresponding to the sequence (0,0,0,...), then the tail equivalence relation and the lexicographic order on its classes for the punctured path space coincide with the corresponding objects for the punctured space of sequences. Thus, your transformation in precisely the classical 2-adic shift with all due consequences.

Comment: Please what is the "2-adic shift" ? Is it Bernoulli shift on $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: After googling I find that the dyadic shift is $Tx=2x \text{ (mod $1$)}$. Please do you know a textbook or an online course on ergodic theory which gives the properties of $T$ ?

Comment: ... in particular I would like to see the corresponding cut-and-stack construction.

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have called it a shift (although it should be clear from my description that it's by no means a Bernoulli shift - one-sided or two-sided). What I mean is the "2-adic odometer transformation", i.e., $z\mapsto z+1$ on 2-adic integers, or, in other words, the adic transformation on the Bratteli diagram, for which each level consists just of a single point, and there are two edges between any two consecutive levels.

Comment: Are you sure ? This is not the usual Bratelli-Vershik graph associated to the odometer, isn't it (showed on page 17 here http://math.unc.edu/Faculty/petersen/lecturespdf.pdf )?

Comment: You mean that the graph a described in the last comment (each level consists just of a single point, and there are two edges between any two consecutive levels) is different from the one in Petersen's lectures? Yes, it is (I don't really understand why he preferred to make things more complicated than they are) - however, the corresponding path spaces are isomorphic, so that the associated adic transformations are precisely the same.

Comment: I meant my graph. I don't see how the odometer can be derived from a cut-and-stack approximation associated to my graph. But I am a beginner in this topic, maybe I need some time to see clearer.

Comment: Your graph is definitely different - however I described a coding which (with the exception of one path) establishes an isomorphism between its path space and the path space of the 2-adic odometer - I have omitted the proof that it's really an isomorphism, but you should be able to fill in the details.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to check the details (this could take a long time since doing mathematics is not my current job)

Comment: @RW Sorry, in fact this is not the graph I am interested in. Please could you take a look at my new question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/105152/is-it-a-known-example-of-adic-transformation-2

Comment: So, the graph itself is the same, but you need to take into account multiplicities of edges?

Comment: @RW Yes, exactly!

Comment: The obvious answer is then that it's a suspension over the 2-adic odometer - will this satisfy you?

Comment: I don't know what is a suspension. I will search but if you have a weblink to propose it would be welcomed !

Comment: @RW is it like "automorphism built under a function" ? (this terminology is from Nadkarni's book "Basic ergodic theory")

Comment: @RW That's right. I have found the definition in Einsiedler & Ward's book. Thanks ! 

@moderators: RW has answered the question of my 2nd post. I don't know whether I should move the 2nd post here ? Sorry for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: @RW I guess you know the Pascal adic and the Euler adic transformations. The Euler graph is the same as the Pascal graph but with multiple edges. Is is true that Euler adic is a suspension over the Pascal adic ?

Comment: Re the edit of 26/08/2012. Maybe before asking any further you would care to at least read the construction of the isomorphism I am talking about? If you did, you could notice that the red and blue paths on your picture correspond to dyadic sequences 0010... and 1010..., which is precisely how it should be for the odometer. There are 3 parts in my answer: (1) the construction; (2) the claim that the tail equivalence relations coincide; (3) the claim that the lexicographic orders on the respective tail equivalence relations coincide. What precisely you don't understand? 

Comment: @RW Damned! I think I was lost because I denoted the blue path by 1101..., and then the action is $z\mapsto z-1$ instead of $z\mapsto z+1$ ! Thank you, this was really helpful ! 

Answer (score 1):

Let me make some trivial remarks about your question. I suppose you are looking for an automorphism of a measure space that is isomorphic to the transformation $T$ defined by the above Bratteli diagram ($T$ is the so called Bratteli-Vershik transformation that acts on the path space $X$ of this diagram). Staying in the context of measurable dynamics, you should clearly define a measure $\mu$ invariant (or quasi-invariant) with respect to $T$. In other words, $T$ must be considered on the support of $\mu$ what is not necessary the whole space $X$. Another thing is that $\mu$ could be non-unique. The concept of isomorphism in measurable dynamics is actually $\rm{mod}\ 0$ isomorphism so that you can ignore sets of measure zero.

I am doubtful that your transformation $T$ is isomorphic to an odometer. In the other question of yours when the right-most edges of the diagram are multiple you will get that an induced transformation $T_A$ is isomorphic to a non-stationary odometer. I suppose this is rather obvious so that let me omit details.

Comment: Thanks. The invariant measures is the first question of my post. But I think there is a natural fully supported invariant measure and this is the invariant measure in which I am interested: start from the vertex at the top of the graph and go to one of the two possible vertices at next level with probabilities $1/2$ and $1/2$.  

Comment: @  Stéphane! You cannot start with an arbitrary probability vector (say (1/2, 1/2) and expect to have an invariant measure (see http://arxiv.org/pdf/0812.1088.pdf for instance). Maybe the following paper would be also interesting for you http://arxiv.org/pdf/0812.1088.pdf

Comment: Correction: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.1621.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Sorry but doing mathematics is not currently my daily job hence I don't have time enough to read many papers. Do you mean $T$ is not invariant with the mesure I proposed ?

Comment: Correction: sorry, obviously I meant $T$ preserves this measure, not T is invariant... 

Comment: @SIB: I have just added an edit to my post. I think RW is right.